# DDEV + NFS + Windows: nfs gives operation not supported

Tags: docker, nfs, ddev

I have successfully installed the nfs service on Windows 10 Pro (NFS Client is activated). It was already working, but suddenly it is not working anymore.

I think NFS Server/Service is successfully configured and installed. `mount \\127.0.0.1/c/Projects N:` I can mount the Share locally.

ddev start (with nfs_mount_enabled: false) works ddev start (with nfs_mount_enabled: true) gives me the 
error:

```
Starting yogamehome-2020... Pushing mkcert rootca certs to ddev-global-cache Pushed mkcert rootca certs to ddev-global-cache Building db Building web Recreating ddev-yogamehome-2020-db ... done Recreating ddev-yogamehome-2020-web ... error Recreating ddev-yogamehome-2020-dba ...

ERROR: for ddev-yogamehome-2020-web Cannot start service web: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-yogamehome-2020_nfsmount/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/c/Projects/yogamehome-2020:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-yogamehome-2020_n Recreating ddev-yogamehome-2020-dba ... doneock: operation not supported

ERROR: for web Cannot start service web: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-yogamehome-2020_nfsmount/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/c/Projects/yogamehome-2020:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-yogamehome-2020_nfsmount/_data, data: addr=127.0.0.1,hard,nolock: operation not supported Encountered errors while bringing up the project. Failed to start yogamehome-2020: Failed to run docker-compose [-f C:\Projects\yogamehome-2020.ddev\docker-compose.yaml -f C:\Projects\yogamehome-2020.ddev\docker-compose.environment.yaml -f C:\Projects\yogamehome-2020.ddev\docker-compose.hosts.yaml up --build -d ], err='exit status 1', stdout='Step 1/6 : ARG BASE_IMAGE Step 2/6 : FROM $BASE_IMAGE ---> 94b0ac137a40 Step 3/6 : ARG username ---> Using cache ---> 56f6d4f186b1 Step 4/6 : ARG uid ---> Using cache ---> 02f90fa967ed Step 5/6 : ARG gid ---> Using cache ---> 2f6228a1a2d0 Step 6/6 : RUN (groupadd --gid $gid "$username" || groupadd "$username" || true) && (useradd -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "$username" --comment '' --uid $uid "$username" || useradd -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "$username" --comment '' "$username") ---> Using cache ---> c3a74d13aecb

Successfully built c3a74d13aecb Successfully tagged drud/ddev-dbserver-mariadb-10.2:v1.13.0-yogamehome-2020-built Step 1/6 : ARG BASE_IMAGE Step 2/6 : FROM $BASE_IMAGE ---> 82d77d5c110a Step 3/6 : ARG username ---> Using cache ---> a4ae9b611d25 Step 4/6 : ARG uid ---> Using cache ---> 9a4a76b8819c Step 5/6 : ARG gid ---> Using cache ---> 6ef62cc84fc9 Step 6/6 : RUN (groupadd --gid $gid "$username" || groupadd "$username" || true) && (useradd -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "$username" --comment '' --uid $uid "$username" || useradd -l -m -s "/bin/bash" --gid "$username" --comment '' "$username") ---> Using cache ---> 764de2909aba

Successfully built 764de2909aba Successfully tagged drud/ddev-webserver:v1.13.0-yogamehome-2020-built ', stderr='Building db Building web Recreating ddev-yogamehome-2020-db ... done Recreating ddev-yogamehome-2020-web ... error Recreating ddev-yogamehome-2020-dba ...

ERROR: for ddev-yogamehome-2020-web Cannot start service web: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-yogamehome-2020_nfsmount/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/c/Projects/yogamehome-2020:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-yogamehome-2020_n Recreating ddev-yogamehome-2020-dba ... doneock: operation not supported

ERROR: for web Cannot start service web: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-yogamehome-2020_nfsmount/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/c/Projects/yogamehome-2020:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-yogamehome-2020_nfsmount/_data, data: addr=127.0.0.1,hard,nolock: operation not supported Encountered errors while bringing up the project.'`
```

Any idea?

I can access it via Explorer and every directory is there, but cannot mount it via ddev.

Most recent version of ddev.

Thanks and kind regards, Harald

shareeditdeleteflag

Answer (score 1):

You have not included C:\Projects in your ~/.ddev/nfs_exports.txt

The error says "failed to mount local volume: mount :/c/Projects/yogamehome-2020:"

It's generally recommended to have your projects in a home directory, but since you have them in \Projects, you'll need to share that in nfs_exports.txt. Add a line like this:

```
C:\Projects > /c/Projects
```

Answer (score -1):

i have exactly that line in my nfs_exports.txt:

> C:\Projects > /c/Projects

As i wrote above i can mount the directory locally. So i gues the Problem is not on the server side.

Thanks,
Harald

Update:
If i start ddev without nfs and then try to mount via ssh:

```
holzm@yogamehome-2020-web:~/nfs-mount$ sudo mount -t nfs 127.0.0.1:/Projects ~/nfs-mount
mount: /home/holzm/nfs-mount: permission denied.
```

Comment: Your error here says that the project is in /home/holzm/nfs-mount, not /Projects. Not sure why you created an answer which isn't an answer. It would be better to create comments on the other answer (and delete this answer).  I'm actually happy to help you with this in a screenshare session if you contact me.